# Wordpress 301 redirect subdirectory with keeping guessing URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am moving a website to WP with WPML. The old website use a wrong country code that I need to redirect domain.com/cz to domain.com/cs

I am using `RewriteRule ^(.*)/cz/(.*)$ $1/cs/$2 [R,L]` which do the trick but there are an issue with WP URL guessing

In WP if you use parent page domain.com/parentpage/mypage, if you type domain.com/mypage it redirect to domain.com/parenpage/mypage automatically

The issue is that my rewrite rule seems override the guessing URL, says:

domain.com/cz/mypage does not redirect to domain.com/cs/parentpage/mypage

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution

```
RewriteRule ^cz/(.*)$ example.org/cs/$1 [R=301,L]
```